# PhoneGap plugin <feature> clobbered when I run phonegap prepare

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

So, I built an app for a client last year using PhoneGap 3.4, and wrote a couple custom native plugins to go with it, for both iOS and Android. They worked fine.

In www/config.xml I specified them as such (actual plugin names omitted):

```
<feature name="MyPluginName">
    <param name="ios-package" value="MyPluginiOSClass" />
    <param name="android-package" value="foo.bar.MyPluginAndroidClass" />
</feature>
```

The plugins themselves are not important, but what is important is that the iOS plugins were implemented in the Xcode project under platforms/ios and the Android plugins were implemented in the Eclipse project under platforms/android.

Now, I also used some of the plugins that come with PhoneGap via phonegap plugin add `foo`, so I have some standard plugins specified:

```
org.apache.cordova.core.console 0.2.0 "Console"
org.apache.cordova.core.device 0.2.1 "Device"
org.apache.cordova.core.file 0.2.1 "File"
org.apache.cordova.core.file-transfer 0.3.1-dev "File Transfer"
org.apache.cordova.core.network-information 0.2.1 "Network Information"
```

Previously, when I ran phonegap prepare on the command line, the target platforms' config.xml would include these 'official' plugins, as well as the ones I specified in www/config.xml

However, a year later, I'm making some updates to the app... **and when I run phonegap prepare, the `<feature>` blocks are ignored.**

Clearly I'm doing something wrong and/or the new build system is less forgiving than before. Since the plugin code belongs to my client I can't open source it and put it on some registry to be managed by pluginman. How can I get my native plugins back in config.xml?

(I'm currently manually putting those `<feature>` blocks back in when the command line tools obliterate them, but I'd rather do this correctly.

Help! (Thanks)

NOTE: I don't use the phonegap command line to build final executables, I use Xcode and Eclipse respectively. I just use the phonegap command line to copy over my www/ folder and build the config.xml

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create the plugin.xml and install the plugins using the cordova CLI with the command

```
cordova plugin add /path/to/your/plugin
```

For more info about the plugin.xml
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.5.0/guide_hybrid_plugins_index.md.html#Plugin%20Development%20Guide